# What is the exact position of X and Y of a VisualElement in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The official Xamarin document describes the X/Y property as *The X/Y position of this element relative to its parents bounds*. But it didn't clarify which position of the visual element if it's quite big.

Say I have a `Frame` element that looks like this. Is the `Frame.X` and `Frame.Y` going to be (X1,Y1), (X2,Y2) or neither?

[image]

Comment: In almost every UI framework out there, components’ coordinates are almost always relative to their parent container’s top-left-corner. ReL your image and question: the answer is (X1,Y1).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the code I tried:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <BoxView Color="Red" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Color="Teal" />        
            <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Color="Purple" />
        </Grid>
        </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

If it doesn't clarify which position, it will start the layout from the top left corner of the parent container.